# Error 22804 in SQL Server 2017 CDC Activation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, cdc

I'm trying to activate CDC in SQL Server 2017. I've done it before, but in this specific database we are having troubles.

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db; -> success

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
     @source_schema = N'SCHEMA',
     @source_name = N'TABLE',
     @role_name = NULL,
     @filegroup_name = N'PRIMARY'; -> success
```

The cdc schema is also successfully created, but after changes on the tables, no data is captured.

In further investigation, we discovered that the jobs created by CDC weren't working.

Checking the logs:

> The Change Data Capture cannot proceed with the action related to the job because transactional replication is enabled in the database (null), but it is unable to retrieve information from the Distributor to determine the state of the Log Reader Agent.
>
> Please make the Distributor database available or disable distribution.
>
> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22804) The call to sp_MScdc_capture_job by the Capture Job for the 'SCHEMA' database failed. Please examine the previous errors to determine the cause of the failure. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22864).
>
> NOTE: The step has been retried the requested number of times (10) without success. The step has failed.

The database is shared with multiple applications, but no one in the company knows or uses replication feature of SQL Server ...

Is there a safe way to solve this problem, without having impacts in other possible unknown applications?

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64) 
Nov  2 2020 19:19:59 
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: From the looks of it, this database has had replication enabled in the past but not removed cleanly/completely. If you truly do not use replication, I'd try running [sp_removedbreplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-removedbreplication-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) against that database.

Comment: @BenThul correct.  Checking sys.databases table, looking for is_published = 1 or is_subscribed = 1 or is_merge_published = 1 or is_distributor = 1, we discovered that someone enabled (partially) replication in the past, but no distributor schema was available. After removing db replication, CDC started working fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What a treat. Glad to help!